# Trouble converting SUMIFS to SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to rewrite a `SUMIFS` formula as `SUMPRODUCT` so that it can reference closed worksheets. The formula checks a column with dates if the date is between two values, and if so sums another column. 
The `SUMIFS` formula is

```
  =SUMIFS('WorkbookName'!$D:$D,'WorkbookName'!$A:$A
  ">=7/1/2015",'WorkbookName'!$A:$A"<=9/30/2015")
```

This works as long as both workbooks are open, however I cannot get my `SUMPRODUCT` to produce anything other than a `"-"`
THis is what I have tried (where `A17` and `A18` are the two dates above)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Workbook'!$A:$A>=A17),('Workbook'!$A:$A<=A18) ('Workbook'!$C:$C))
```

Comment: just needed the -- infront of second criteria, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your syntax is not quite correct (either that or the post editor corrupted your formula):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Workbook!$A1:$A1000>=A17),--(Workbook!$A1:$A1000<=A18),Workbook!$C1:$C1000)`

I strongly recommend that you don't use entire column references with SUMPRODUCT. Hence my use of 1000 as an upper row reference.

Feel free to amend this value to meet your requirements, though you should be careful not to make it too arbitrarily large, since, for each additional cell referenced, extra calculation will be required.

And that applies whether those additional cells are technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not. With some functions, e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), you can get away with referencing entire columns with no detriment to performance, though not with functions which operate over arrays, such as AGGREGATE, SUMPRODUCT, and any construction requiring CSE.

Even better, make the ranges dynamic, such that they automatically adjust as your data expands/contracts, thus offering optimal calculation efficiency. I can show you how to do this if you like.

Regards

Comment: how would you go about making the range elastic? the table it is referencing is updated daily with more values

Comment: What is in column A? Numerics?

Comment: column A is dates in mm/dd/yyyy, c is numbers

Comment: Thanks. Will there ever be any blanks in column C?

Comment: most of the columns no, but in one of the formulas i am running there will be

Comment: I don't understand your reply, which does not seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Workbook'!$A:$A>=A17), --('Workbook'!$A:$A<=A18), ('Workbook'!$C:$C))
```

Create the formula with both workbooks open. After that you can close the external workbook and the references should adjust to a full path and workbook name.

It isn't entirely clear to me why you want to switch from the more efficient [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) to the older [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) unless you were trying to provide compatibility for circa xl2003 versions.

Comment: SUMIFS will only return a result if the workbook being referenced is open. SUMPRODUCT does not suffer that drawback.

Comment: You're right of course. I guess I was just thinking about existing formulas not reverting to a #VALUE! error the way a new formula does.

Answer (score 0):

If the code above is correct, there are two errors. The right syntax would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Workbook'!$A:$A>=A17), --('Workbook'!$A:$A<=A18), ('Workbook'!$C:$C))
```

The second part needs the -- as well, and the second comma was missing. I tried it over here and with those changes didn't have any problems.